# Does phase distorsion occur if I use filtfilt?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I've a theoretical question about filter. I've got a signal sampled at 500Hz and I have to lowpass it (0-30Hz ). I use a butterworth filter and the
gain and phase plot are:

[image]

As you can see, the phase amplitude shows a ripple at the high frequencies (almost 200hz). I've two questions

1. Does the phase ripple occur because the bandwidth is too narrow?
2. Since I delete all the frequencies above 30Hz, does the ripple affect my data? (even if I use filfilt?)

Comment: 1)I assume that this  phase ripple you see there is due to computational errors, but this is just an assumption. As your Fs is 500Hz your filter is not too narrow, nevertheless, the corner frequency, the transition width, the order are all factors which together have an effect on your filter performance. 2) as long you are not downsampling or upsamling,it wont effect your passband. So the idea behind filtfilt is to get a zero-phase distortion, so it cancels all phase distortion

Answer (score 1):

A Butterworth filter has non-zero, non-constant phase. That's what you see in the graph. Note that the phase is a smooth function; the "ripple" you see is just the usual jump from `-pi` to `pi` as the phase decreases. You can use [`unwrap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) to remove those jumps.

If you apply [`filtfilt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) you filter the signal first forward and then backward in time. This is equivalent to applying a single filter wit zero phase, and with an amplitude that is the square of the original one. So yes, with `filfilt` you avoid phase distortion.